# Value Error:Cannot assign queryset to attribute it must be instance

Tags: django, django-models

I have models.py

```
class employees(models.Model):
  emp_id=models.PositiveIntegerField()
  emp_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
  emp_lname = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
  emp_loc=models.CharField(max_length=5,choices=LOCATION)
  manager_id=models.ForeignKey('self',null=True,blank=True)  

class leave(models.Model): 
  employee = models.ForeignKey(employees, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='1')
  start_date = models.DateField()
  end_date = models.DateField()
  status=models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=LEAVE_STATUS,default='P')
  ltype=models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=LEAVE_TYPE)
  message=models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)  

class notify(models.Model):
  sender_id=models.ForeignKey(leave, related_name='%(class)s_sendername')
  receiver_id=models.ForeignKey(leave,related_name='%(class)s_receivername')
  date_time=models.DateTimeField()
```

I have views.py

```
 def accept(request):
   approved_emp_id=leave.objects.filter(id=accept_id);
approving_emp_id=leave.objects.filter(employee__emp_id=request.user.username);
accept_notify=notify(sender_id=approving_emp_id,  receiver_id=approved_emp_id,date_time=datetime.datetime.now(),viewed='N');
accept_notify.save()
```

When I want to save values to database I am getting error as `ValueError: Cannot assign "<QuerySet [<leave: 121-geeta-2017-10-04-2017-10-06-C-V-2017-09-27 07:48:36.288873+00:00>]>": "notify.sender_id" must be a "leave" instance.`

Where am I going wrong `approving_emp_id` and `approved_emp_id` are both leave instance only.

Comment: use `leave.objects.get()` instead of `leave.objects.filter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `QuerySet` when the arguments should be an instance. A `QuerySet` is a list of instances. Pass only one instance. Use `leave.objects.get()` instead of `leave.objects.filter()`.

[`objects.get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get) returns a single instance where [`objects.filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) returns a `QuerySet`.

```
def accept(request):
    approved_emp_id = leave.objects.get(id = accept_id)
    approving_emp_id = leave.objects.get(employee__emp_id = request.user.username)
    accept_notify = notify(sender_id = approving_emp_id, receiver_id = approved_emp_id, date_time = datetime.datetime.now(), viewed = 'N')
    accept_notify.save()
```

Another way is [`slicing`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets) the `QuerySet`.

```
def accept(request):
    approved_emp_id = leave.objects.filter(id = accept_id)[0]
    approving_emp_id = leave.objects.filter(employee__emp_id = request.user.username)[0]
    accept_notify = notify(sender_id = approving_emp_id, receiver_id = approved_emp_id, date_time = datetime.datetime.now(), viewed = 'N')
    accept_notify.save()
```